# Google Tag Manager: trigger click on div ID with other elements inside

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have created a couple of click triggers in Google Tag Manager to track some areas of my site and I was surprised that the figures were so low. I have realised why but couldn't find a way around it.

Code example:

```
<li id="myUniqueID"><i class="material-icon">mail_outline</i></li>
```

If I create a click trigger on "myUniqueID", it only captures the clicks in the area outside the space occupied by the icon. If I click right into the icon, the listener is not fired.

Is there a way to capture all clicks based on a unique ID or class that would take clicks of all sub-elements into account.

It's probably something stupid that I have overlooked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your trigger to Click All Elements that Match a CSS Selector.

As a selector, try using `#myUniqueID, #myUniqueID *`

The second selector selects all descendants/children of whoever has the myUniqueID id.

Comment: thanks again! It worked!
For those who want the complete path:
Trigger Type = click on all elements
Condition = some clicks
Click Element => Correspond to CSS selector